# Call argument from multi returned arguments function using Python

Tags: python, return

By using Python : I want to call just one argument from defined function (Angles) which return two arguments theta and phi. How can I call just theta value from Angles funcition and assign it to x value?

```
values = [1,-1]    
g = np.random.choice(values)
q= np.random.choice(values)   
def Angles ():
    theta = (((1 + g*g - ((1 - g*g)/(1 - g + 2*g*q))**2)/(2*g)))
    phi = 2 * math.radians(180) * q
    return theta,phi

x = cos(theta)
```

Comment: What do you mean _call_ just the theta value? Why do you do `x = cos(theta)` if you want `x` to be equal to theta?

Comment: It doesn't return arguments; it returns (a tuple of) two values computed from a pair of global variables. An argument is a value passed to a function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `Angles` first; `theta` will be the first element of the tuple returned by `Angles`.

```
th, ph = Angles()
x = cos(th)
```

or

```
x = cos(Angles()[0])
```